# Why report：“No mapping found for HTTP request with URI “

Tags: spring, web, model-view-controller

first time build a springmvc web project,use jetty as web container,but when jetty started, but when request the url:"http://localhost:8080/hello/mvc" the 
broswer report:
"Problem accessing /hello/mvc. Reason: ".And the console report:"十一月 18, 2018 10:34:16 上午 org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
警告: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hello/mvc] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
"

**my web.xml:**

```
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <!--param-name>/WEB-INF/configs/spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-name-->
            <param-value>classpath*:spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- scan the package and the sub package -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.zhangbing.springmvc">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <!-- if you use annotation you must configure following setting -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

       <!-- configure the InternalResourceViewResolver -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          id="internalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name ="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <!-- 前缀 -->
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/" />
        <!-- 后缀 -->
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>`enter code here`
</beans>
```

The hierarch of my project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxiwq.png)
circled by blue line is the controller

**The contoller helloMvcController:**
    package com.zhangbing.springmvc.controller;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class helloMvcController {
    @RequestMapping("/mvc")
    public String helloMvc()
    {
        return "home";
    }
```

i search lots question like this,but no one can solved my problem,please help.

Comment: can not work with same output,thank you.

Comment: any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, Spring can not find your controller.The problem might be with the component scan.

Please change your component scan directive from

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.zhangbing.springmvc">
```

to

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.zhangbing.springmvc.*">
```

Then lets see what is the output.

Comment: there is a (*) at the end. Did you check it?

Comment: yes， <context:component-scan base-package="com.zhangbing.springmvc.*">